# Where is UFOpedia?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I can't find [**UFOpedia**](http://ufopedia.csignal.org/ufopedia/) in the new XCOM.

Is it there at all? If it is, how do I access it?

If not, then where can I see things like for example detailed stats for weapons, armour and aliens?

Comment: I first though you meant http://www.ufopaedia.org...

Comment: @Zommuter: added link, for those who haven't played UFO:EU

Comment: Aww, nostalgia :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no UFOpedia anywhere in the game. In stead, the information is sprinkled around the game, to more or less appropriate places.

**Research** and **Engineering** screens house the largest collections of data.
The **Research Archives** have all the research results in them and have a rather detailed description of most things that go though your *Research Lab*. However, no actual stats can be found here.
The **Build/Buy Items** menu has a wealth of information on everything you can build yourself. Besides the flavor texts obviously visible, actual stats for an item (where appropriate) can be found by pressing the question mark button on in the lower left corner.

Rest of the information is more out of the way.
More item stats can be found via the **Solider Layout** screen, by pressing the icon on the lower left corner of the item's picture, be that in the *Inventory* or the *Locker*. This is also the only way to see stats on equipment you don't build yourself, like basic weapons and granades.
Clicking on any ship in the **Hangar Ship List** gives you acces to the stats on your available ship weapons, including *Avalance Missles* that you can't find in the *Engineering*. Click either *Weapon Info* or *Edit Layout*. You can also find some info on the ships themselves, altough they don't have any accurate stats.
**Gray Market** in the *Situation Room* gives you a bit more flavor text on some items.

The rest, including complete lists of accurate alien abilities, can be found in combat by targeting an alien and clicking **More Info** on the thing that shows your chanses of hitting it.
You'll also find more info on your own soliders' abilities by clicking the **Solider Info** button in lower left corner, next to the turn end button. Or, just by hitting F1.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case. I can't understand why would they remove UFOpedia from the new version.

Answer (score 0):

I too miss the UFOpedia, however I have found [this website](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Enemy_Unknown_(EU2012)) which appears to have what you are looking for!